Nux3 - server util - custom event handler wrapper
I'm quite new to Nuxt and I've been moved on a Nuxt3 project recently.
I want to have every of the server api endpoint to handle their business logic in a try-catch and in case of error format an error log (I've successfully introduced winston).
Given this desiderata I stumbled upon Nuxt3 own server/utils example that does exactly what I need, the only problem I know nothing about typescript and the docs doesn't show how to use the provided example.
I converted the example to plain JS using an online converter and got this:
export const defineWrappedResponseHandler = handler =>
  defineEventHandler(async event => {
    try {
      // do something before the route handler
      const response = await handler(event)
      // do something after the route handler
      return { response }
    } catch (err) {
      // Error handling
      return { err }
    }
  })

but still: how do I use this code into my apis?
I put the converted code into server/utils/customEventHandler.js and tried with
export default customEventHandler(
    defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
        // do buiness logic and return data
    })
);

but calling the endpoint (from the browser) I  get a 500 response with
{
    "url": "/api/account/user/login",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "statusMessage": "",
    "message": "Invalid lazy handler result. It should be a function:",
    "stack": ""
}


Ok, found the solution.
First of all, the wrapper code is wrong: it should export default a function (as the error suggested):
// ~/server/utils/customEventHandler.js

export default (handler) =>
    defineEventHandler(async event => {
        try {
            const response = await handler(event);
            return { response };
        }
        catch(err){
            throw err;
        }
});

Moreover I rethrowed the error to let Nuxt handle the response.
And then used it in my api:
// ~/server/api/my/route.js

export default customEventHandler(
    defineEventHandler(async (event) => {

        // business logic here

        return { /*something*/ };
    })
);

This way I can "standardize" the try-catch behavior and the error handling of all my api endpoint.
Any comment or suggestion is highly appreciated, if there is a better solutionI want to know it.
